# How to enforce complete documentation on Kotlin code

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, javadoc, kdoc

What plugin or tool should I use to enforce complete kdoc documentation on new Kotlin code? 
Java code is checked by checkstyle with Sun's rule set, I need a Kotlin's analogue for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [detekt](https://detekt.dev) and its [comments rule set](https://detekt.dev/docs/rules/comments). Especially [UndocumentedPublicClass](https://detekt.dev/docs/rules/comments#undocumentedpublicclass), [UndocumentedPublicFunction](https://detekt.dev/docs/rules/comments#undocumentedpublicfunction) and [UndocumentedPublicProperty](https://detekt.dev/docs/rules/comments#undocumentedpublicproperty).

It integrates with Maven via [Ant task](https://detekt.dev/docs/gettingstarted/mavenanttask).